# Why does JAX-WS need wrapper classes?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I created a simple webservice, which implements an add operation, and created some client files with wsimport. Now I want to include as less as possible wsdl specific artifacts. Here is an example of how the web service will be called:

```
String serviceNamespace = "http://jws.samples.geronimo.apache.org/";
String serviceName = "CalculatorServiceService";
QName serviceQN = new QName(serviceNamespace, serviceName);
Service service = Service.create(new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebService/calculator?wsdl"), serviceQN);

String portNamespace = "http://jws.samples.geronimo.apache.org/";
String portName = "CalculatorServicePort";
QName portQN = new QName(portNamespace, portName);
Calculator myProxy = (Calculator) service.getPort(portQN, Calculator.class);
```

But it seems like I have to include wrapper classes for every message. For example the result message of the add operation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "addResponse", propOrder = { "_return" })
public class AddResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "return")
    protected int _return;
    public int getReturn() {
        return _return;
    }
    public void setReturn(int value) {
        this._return = value;
    }
}
```

These wrappers are used within annotations in the service interface:

```
@WebService(name = "Calculator", targetNamespace = "http://jws.samples.geronimo.apache.org/")
public interface Calculator {
    @WebMethod
    @RequestWrapper(className = "org.example.webservices.clients.dynamicproxy.Add")
    @ResponseWrapper(className = "org.example.webservices.clients.dynamicproxy.AddResponse")
    public int add(
        @WebParam(name = "value1", targetNamespace = "")
        int value1,
        @WebParam(name = "value2", targetNamespace = "")
        int value2);
}
```

If the annotations are removed, the web service won't run.

> com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class org.example.webservices.clients.dynamicproxy.jaxws.Add is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?

But why do I need those wrappers? Couldn't JAX-WS create those wrappers on-the-fly? Do you see any information, which couldn't be retrieved from the wsdl file?

Comment: Found one document which is worthwhile to read. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxwsdynclient.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your service is WRAPPED, not BARE, and so the top-level item in the message has to be a type with the same name as the operation. In 'classic' JAX-WS, this requires you to add a wrapper type.

If you use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org), it will automatically generate these wrappers with ASM.

Answer (score 1):

In the service interface if you have an entry:

```
@WebResult(targetNamespace = "http://jws.samples.geronimo.apache.org/")
```

before the **add** method in the Calculator interface, then you can get the wrapper classes created by the JAX-WS client on-the-fly using the following code:

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class TestWS{

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
     URL url = "url to wsdl"

     QName qname = new QName("http://jws.samples.geronimo.apache.org/", "Name of your service" );
     Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
     Calculator calcPort = service.getPort(Calculator.class);
     System.out.println("Result of 1+2 is " + calcPort.add(1,2));     
  }
}
```